# Can you add a class to a 'label' tag?

Tags: css, class, label, forms, styling

This is probably a stupid question but I was just wondering if it's possible add a class to a 'label' tag instead of having to wrap it in a 'span' tag to style it. I'm reading "CSS: The Missing Manual" and it's telling me that in order to style a bunch of label tags, I should wrap each one I wanted to style with a 'span' tag.

```
<label class="name">Name:</label>
```

Comment: You can give it a class, yes.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. The label tag supports all the global attributes specified in the HTML Attribute Reference.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_label_tag.htm

Global attributes list: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_attributes_reference.htm

Comment: Okay thank you. Why would the book I'm reading tell me to add a 'span' tag around the 'label' tags then to add a class and style them?

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help. Usually span is used inline on small chunks of code. Div is the standard way and should always be considered first.

Comment: Hey, did you notice the code in your link is missing the closing label tag?

Comment: it did not work for me `<label for="foo" class="neat"> Some Text </label><input......><style> .neat{display: inline-block; width: 200px; text-align: right;}</style>`